# getting value in front of checkbox

Tags: javascript, lwc

```
<template if:true={allFolderNames}>
            <template for:each={allFolderNames} for:item="fName">
                <div key={fName}>
                    <div class ="container" >
                        <lightning-layout multiple-rows class="slds-list_horizontal">
                            <lightning-layout-item >
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox" onclick={getFolderID}></lightning-input>  
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item  >
                                {fName}
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
                           
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </template>
```

My requirement is whenever I check on checkbox I want to get fname in front of it. I craeted on function getFolderID in js file but don't know how to proceed further. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can you use document.createElement() or if that doesnt work you can just

Comment: Can you please give me an example how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).